# Modulus of Continuity Is Continuous at x for Fixed $\delta$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, analysis

Suppose the space $C[0,1]$ equipped with the usual uniform distance. For any $x\in C$, define the modulus of continuity function as $w_x(\delta)=w(x,\delta)=sup_{|s-t|<\delta}|x(s)-x(t)|,\  0<\delta\leq 1$. Prof. Billingsley says, in Convergence of Probability Measures, that "since $|w_x(\delta)-w_y(\delta)|\leq2\rho(x,y)$, $w(x,\delta)$ is, for fixed positive $\delta$, continuous in x."

I don't understand why $|w_x(\delta)-w_y(\delta)|\leq2\rho(x,y)$. Could you help me solve this puzzle. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will prove that
\begin{equation}
  w_x(\delta) \leq w_y(\delta) + 2 \rho (x, y) \tag{1}\label{eq1}
\end{equation}
or, equivalently,
\begin{equation}
  w_x(\delta) - w_y(\delta) \leq 2 \rho (x, y)
\end{equation}
for any $x, y \in C [0, 1]$.
Because of the symmetry in $x$ and $y$, this also implies
\begin{equation}
  w_y(\delta) - w_x(\delta) \leq 2 \rho (x, y)
,\end{equation}
from which the result promptly follows.

To prove (\ref{eq1}), we apply the triangle inequality and a property of the supremum:
\begin{align*}
  w_x (\delta) &= \sup_{|s - t| < 1} |x(s) - x(t)| \\
  &\leq \sup_{|s - t| < 1} |x(s) - y(s)| + |y(s) - y(t)| + |y(t) - x(t)| \\
  &\leq \sup_{|s - t| < 1} |x(s) - y(s)| + \sup_{|s - t| < 1} |y(s) - y(t)| + \sup_{|s - t| < 1} |y(t) - x(t)| \\
  &= \rho (x, y) + w_y (\delta) + \rho (x, y) \\
  &= 2\rho (x, y) + w_y (\delta)
.\end{align*}